# I have an issue with a vba code I developed

Tags: excel, vba

I developed the vba code below to calculate cumulative production up to one date in the column "K" by adding amounts in the column "I" corresponding to dates less than the one in the column "K"

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub Gp()
    Dim date2 As Double            'Same p/z production Dates'
    Dim Gp As Double               'Cumulative production volumes"
    Dim fraction As Double
    Dim Daysmonth As Double
    Dim Days As Double
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

        Gp = 0
        j = 3
        For i = 4 To 43
              date2 = Cells(i, "K")
              Do While (Cells(j, "A") < date2)
                  Gp = Gp + Cells(j, "I")
                  j = j + 1
               Loop
               Daysmonth = Cells(j, "A") - Cells(j - 1, "A")
               Days = date2 - Cells(j - 1, "A")
               fraction = Cells(j, "I") * Days / Daysmonth
               Gp = Gp + fraction
               Cells(i, "M") = Gp
               Gp = (Gp + Cells(j, "I")) - fraction
               j = j + 1
        Next i
End Sub
```

This code takes the first cell of the "K" column and look all the dates less than date in the "A" column. Then it add all the amounts in the "I" column for those corresponding dates. Then if the date in the column "A" is in the same month and year of the date in the column "K" it will calculate the fraction of the amount corresponding to those days. Everything is alright until 8/14/80 when calculating the fraction it gives -17 instead of 14 days for 8/14/80 - 8/31/80. It gives me 6304593 and it should give me 6350518.484.

This is a picture of my answers in the column "M" and the right answers in the column "N". They are very similar but not the same for some dates

Calculated cumulative and right answers next to it

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please post the excel data in plain text instead of image file? That will help me to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

> "when calculating the fraction it gives -17 instead of 14 days for 8/14/80 - 8/31/80"

Not sure where you are getting the 14 days. Since 8/31/80 is in the future it would be 17 days after 8/14/80. Based upon your formula of 8/14/80 - 8/31/80, it arrives at -17 which is correct.

If you are okay to include dates greater than 'date2', you could use the built in 'Abs()' function to always make the result positive and that should correct the calculation.

```
Days = Abs(date2 - Cells(j - 1, "A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Output of `8/14/80 - 8/31/80` should be -17 only , instead of 14 days. Just to check, I have tried your code and replaced the value -17 with 14 then output i am getting is `7255151.33` instead of `6350518.484`.

I think fraction should not be calculated in this case(8/14/80 - 8/31/80) as the primary condition is date in column K(8/14/80) should be greater than Date in column A(8/31/80) which is failing in this case.

And if it is required then you can check if the output of `date2 - Cells(j - 1, "A")` is negative then replace it with `Cells(j - 1, "A")-date2` to make the result positive.